# Paypal: Handle multi-currencies payment

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I used to sell products in euros but I may need to handle different currencies due to a translation.

I think the best solution for me is to sell in euros (my currency) regardless of the user's currency.

The only thing I would like to do is to set the price in euros (i.e. 50€) and show the approx price in the user's currency (i.e. 36£ GBP) following paypal's conversion ratio so the users know approx how much will be charged. It's a kind of what happen in ebay.

I took a look to paypal documentation but everything is very confused.

Anyone already did it? Any suggestion on what to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, but I don't recommend you guessing and approximating PayPal's currency conversion rates.

As it sounds like you know, your basic choice is this: what is the currency of the transaction (ie, what is the buyer paying you)?

If you choose that the payment be in Euros, then simply do that. PayPal will display the purchase as being in Euros, and will allow the buyer to pay using Euros *or other currency they may have*, and will do the conversion for the buyer, showing them the rates etc. Your account will always receive Euros. The buyer knows/sees exactly how much they will be charged on the PayPal pages. Or at least, they will if PayPal is doing the payment on a PayPal page. If you use Express Checkout or Direct Payment or something where you do an API payment, the buyer will not see it -- but their account can still draw on their other currency balances or pull from a card denominated in another currency. If you do this, I would let the buyer work out in their head what the conversion would be; approximating it and telling them an approximate conversion just opens you up to angry customers (and potentially even legal liability) if the conversion is not exactly what you tell them. Customers should know that if they are paying for something that has a cost in Euro and they have another currency that some conversion will need to be performed, and should be aware of the general conversion between the currencies or they should not be shopping. Or they can google it :). I don't believe PayPal provides any API to get their current exchange rates, and they are dynamic anyway, meaning they could change (a little) even between you retrieving them and the payment happening.

The other option is to list your goods in a variety of currencies which the buyer could pay in, and *once the funds reach your account* the money can be auto-converted to Euros. This will result in your customers paying a (to them) consistent price in each currency, and you receiving slightly different amounts (in Euro) for each purchase as exchange rates fluctuate.

Note that this means there are two places currency conversions can happen: buyer funds into the transaction currency, and transaction currency into your holding currency. And they can both happen on the same transaction. Meaning a buyer could pay using USD (or even using some USD and some GBP!) for a payment that is in GBP which is converted to EUR when it arrives in your account.

There is a third option: you can receive payments in multiple currencies, NOT autoconvert when they enter your holdings, and maintain multiple currency holdings. You can use these holdings to make outbound payments (refunds, payments to suppliers, etc), convert some or all funds between these holdings at any time, or convert when withdrawing funds from PayPal. But it doesn't sound like this is what you are after.